# Get list of unique multi-sets

Tags: python, collections, unique, combinations, multiset

How can I uniquify the following list in Python:

```
all_the_ways = [(5,), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2),\
                (1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Desired output is:

```
[(5,), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

i.e. I need to get rid of tuples that have the same set of numbers but in different order.

I tried

```
set(all_the_ways)
```

but it only transpose elements.

And when I do

```
list(map(set, all_the_ways))
```

the things getting only worse:

```
[{5}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {1}]
```

In other words I need to convert inner tuple to a *collection that allows multiple equal items (`set` is not suitable) and for which permutations of elements don't change the collection itself (kinda like C++'s `multiset`)*

Comment: What should be the output when `all_the_ways = [(2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1)]`?

Comment: first or second tuple, doesn't matter

Comment: So, the result should be in `all_the_ways`?

Comment: first or second tuple or even (1,2,2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
list(set(tuple(sorted(s)) for s in all_the_ways))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 2), (5,), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2)]
```

It will mangle the order of each tuple though. I'm assuming that doesn't matter, as tuples containing the same set of numbers are considered the same for your case. What this implies is that in the end, the output list might contain tuples that are not among the original input, for example (credit to @thefourtheye):

```
all_the_ways = [(2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1)]
# Output: [(1, 2, 2)]
```

This may or may not be a problem, and if it is, you can use the more robust solutions which are already mentioned in the other excellent answers.

Comment: If the combination `(1, 2, 2)` doesn't exist in `all_the_ways`, this might be a problem. But not sure if it is okay with the OP. Already +1ed

Comment: That's very true, as I have mentioned in the answer. I have decided not to address the ordering issue to provide a simpler perspective, just in case it is not a constraint in this problem. +1s to all the order-preserving solutions! :)

Comment: Actually, its not about the order. When `all_the_ways = [(2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1)]`, output will be `[(1, 2, 2)]`, which is not there in `all_the_ways`. This might be a problem, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I actually see it as another "internal ordering" issue there.

Comment: Looks like [OP is fine with this output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356512/get-list-of-unique-multi-sets?noredirect=1#comment35778162_23356512) :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to identify the unique multisets:

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> all_the_ways = [(5,), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2),\
                (1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
>>> result = []
>>> seen = set()
>>> for tup in all_the_ways:
        key = tuple(sorted(Counter(tup).items())) # unique signature
        if key not in seen:
            result.append(tup)
        seen.add(key)

>>> result
[(5,), (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: I was thinking about this only, but couldn't proceed further as they are not hashable... :(

Comment: @thefourtheye Once the counting is made, a sort of the items makes canonical ordering, and tuplizing makes it hashable :-)

Comment: Why not simply `Counter(tuple(sorted(i)) for i in all_the_ways).keys()` ?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger Actually I used `frozenset` and solved it, but sacrificed the order :( Please check my answer.

Comment: Anyway +1 to yours, as it maintains the order :)

Answer (score 2):

If the Order doesn't matter you can use this

```
from collections import Counter
>>> {frozenset(Counter(tup).items()):tup for tup in data}.values()
# [(1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (5,)]
```

If you want to maintain the Order,

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
OrderedDict([frozenset(Counter(tup).items()),tup] for tup in data).values()
# [(5,), (1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

In both the solutions we rely on `frozenset`, because the `set` objects are not hashable as they are mutable. In the first case, we construct a dictionary with the frequency of the numbers (determined with `Counter`) as the key and the current tuple as the value corresponding to that. Once the dictionary construction is completed, we take all the values, which correspond to the  tuples.

In the second case, we simply use `OrderedDict` to maintain the order.

Comment: +1 For the the nice combination of OrderedDict, frozenset, and Counter.

Answer (score 1):

May be this?:

```
result = {tuple(sorted(x)) for x in all_the_ways}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from collections import OrderedDict
print OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), all_the_ways)).keys()
```

or

```
print set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), all_the_ways))
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you consider two elements "equal" if they contain the same values, regardless of the order.

So you can "canonicalize" each tuple by sorting it, convert back to tuples (so they are hashable), and remove duplicates using `set` again:

```
set( tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in all_the_ways )
```

You can also preserve the original "outer" order, by using `OrderedSet` instead of `set`.